# Pause python script wait for key press

Tags: python

I have a relatively simple script and a potentially simple question. 
Around the internet I've gathered a few solutions on how to use direct key press' as input in my python code. I'd prefer these to raw_input as it feels faster. Like if I have a menu with 3 options, and 3 options in each of those, I can easily press 3 then 2 on my keyboard to get where I need to go.

The code is:

```
import keyboard
import time

def mainmenu():
    while(True):
        print ('1. Scan')
        print ('2. Ping')
        print ('3. Exit')

        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
            print ('Option 1\n')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
            print ('Option 2\n')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
            print ('Exiting\n')
            exit(0)
        else:
            print ('none of the specified options were chosen')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            exit(0)
mainmenu()
```

I just want something that will pause the code where I can press a key. 
I can't use `time.sleep()` for some reason. It doesn't like inputs in the split second before or after it either. 
It would be awesome if I could get a function to do it so I could input it elsewhere along the way.

If I didn't have my else statement at the end, the while loop just keeps going. 
If I don't have it in a while loop the script prints the options in 1 second and then defaults to else, because I haven't pressed a key in the 1 second. 
I know it works because if I take out the else statement and while its spamming the options over and over I press 3, IDLE asks if I'd like to kill the script while its running.

Comment: Of course I had a more than just a quick Google. If you read my question, I don't want to input my code, I want it to read key press. The problem with that is it doesn't pause to wait for key press. But now it does, so don't worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyboard.read_key()` as it will block the execution of the rest of code until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event's name or, if missing, its scan code.

```
import keyboard
import time

def mainmenu():
    print ('1. Scan')
    print ('2. Ping')
    print ('3. Exit')

    while(True):
        a = keyboard.read_key()

        if a == '1' or a == '2':
            print("Option {} was pressed\n".format(a))
        elif a == '3':
            print("Exiting\n")
            exit(0)
        else:
            print("None\n")
            exit(0)

        time.sleep(0.3)

mainmenu()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use input() to have the same effect.

```
import time

def mainmenu():
    while(True):
        print ('1. Scan')
        print ('2. Ping')
        print ('3. Exit')

        x= input()
        if x==1:
            print ('Option 1\n')
        elif x==2:
            print ('Option 2\n')
        elif x==3:
            print ('Exiting\n')
            exit(0)
        else:
            print ('none of the specified options were chosen')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            exit(0)
mainmenu()
```

Comment: As OP mentioned that he does not want to use `raw_input`, which like `input`, required addition press of `return` (two keystrokes instead of just one).

Comment: Yeah, Negi did you read my question? Also I submitted an edit on your code, as it requires the if/elif statements to look more like `if x==1:` than `if x == '1':`

Answer (score 0):

import time

def mainmenu():
while(True):
print ('1. Scan')
print ('2. Ping')
print ('3. Exit')

```
    x=input()
    if x=='1':
        print ('Option 1\n')
    elif x=='2':
        print ('Option 2\n')
    elif x=='3':
        print ('Exiting\n')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print ('none of the specified options were chosen')
        time.sleep(1)
```

mainmenu()

Comment: input() take whatever we type  as string
or we can casting like this x=int(input()) then we type integer for valuation
as x==1 e.i.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).