# How to display an image (on a canvas) selected via filedialog?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I started a project a few days ago but unfortunately I'm stuck. I would like to make an image editor (a very simple one ;D) where a choose an image by using the filedialog then I would have the possibilty to make few modifications like rotations. My problem is that I can choose the image but once I did, I can't show the image on the canvas.

It says : "name 'image' is not define"

I think my problem is that the program want to show the image on the canvas but I haven't selected it yet.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

#function to select my image by using the filedialog
def select_image(): 
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    image = Image.open(file_path)

#button to press to open filedialog
select = Button(root, text="select an image", command=select_image)
select.pack()

#the canvas where the image will be display
canvas = Canvas(root, width= 100, height=100, bg="grey")
canvas.pack()

image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image_tk)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Two problems: 1. You’re not actually calling your function select_image() from the main body of your code, and 2. You’re setting ‘image’ for the first time inside that function (which is never called), so when you get to the bottom, image remains undefined.  I would refactor your code to return the image object from your function.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create an image object before you have an image file to display, but not in the way you're doing it. You simply need to create an empty image object and keep track of the image object id, and then reconfigure that object inside of `select_image`.

For example, don't define `image_tk` in the main program. Change the line that creates the image item on the canvas to this:

```
image_id = canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor="nw")
```

(note: without the `anchor` option, the center of the image will be at 0,0. I'm guessing you want the upper-left corner of the image to be at 0,0).

Next, in `select_image` is where you do all of the work of getting the image, saving a reference to it (to avoid it being deleted when the function returns), and showing it in the canvas. It would look something like this:

```
def select_image(): 
    # ask the user for the filename
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # only show the image if they chose something
    if file_path:
        # open the file
        image = Image.open(file_path)

        # create the image object, and save it so that it
        # won't get deleted by the garbage collector
        canvas.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        # configure the canvas item to use this image
        canvas.itemconfigure(image_id, image=canvas.image_tk)
```

Answer (score -1):

You’ve got a couple of problems here:

1. You are never calling your function! Your code ignores
   `select_image()` after it is defined
2. The variable `image` is only defined inside your (uncalled) function, so when you try to use it via `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, it is
   undefined.

Try returning the image object this way:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

#function to select my image by using the filedialog
def select_image(): 
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return Image.open(file_path)

#button to press to open filedialog
select = Button(root, text="select an image", command=select_image)
select.pack()

#the canvas where the image will be display
canvas = Canvas(root, width= 100, height=100, bg="grey")
canvas.pack()

image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(select_image())
canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image_tk)


root.mainloop()
```

Note that you are not checking for errors or cancellation in your select_image() function. You’d be better off handling cancel or error inside the function too

Comment: Thank you it works a lot better now ! But when I start the program, the filedialog opens automaticaly, is there a way to open the filedialog only when the button is pressed ?

Comment: Yes, see this question: [Pause Python Script Wait for Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871649/pause-python-script-wait-for-key-press). As a courtesy, it would be nice if you would either upvote or accept my answer, as I spent some time on this. That’s how this site incentivizes people go be helpful to each other. :-)

Comment: Your first statement seems to be incorrect. `select_image` isn't ignored, because it's called when the user clicks the button. Also, it's generally a bad idea to open a dialog before mainloop is called. It will sometimes work on some platforms, but it will cause problems on Windows.