# How do you press a specific key to do something in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I want to know to press a specific key to do something in python and no, not the keyboard library it requires root permissions. I could just do `sudo /bin/python3.7 "path of python file"` but that's gonna be a pain. by the way here's my python code:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as auto
import time

auto.hotkey('alt', 'F2')
auto.write('mousepad')
time.sleep(int(1))
auto.write('do you want to start game?')

keyboard.wait('y')
```

Comment: What if you put the `.wait()` under a `while True:`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pause python script wait for key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871649/pause-python-script-wait-for-key-press)

Comment: nope, not at all.

Comment: i don't want keyboard module.

Comment: fell free to close this: found solution.

Comment: perhaps you can post your solution? You are allowed to and can select it as the answer.

Comment: the problem was i was on linux, on linux you need administrator privileges to use keyboard module. i had to use a different module for it to work.

Comment: i could have wrote an sh file :( sudo python3 (path of the python file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pynput.keyboard import *
import pyautogui as auto
import time

auto.hotkey('alt', 'F2')
time.sleep(int(1))
auto.write('mousepad')
time.sleep(int(1))
auto.write('do you want to start game?')

if key == Key.y:
    # Stop listener
    return False

def on_press(key):
    doing_something_here()


with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=None) as listener:
    listener.join()
```